# Couldn't send 'multipart/form-data;boundary=' request through Postman

Tags: postman, tableau-api

I am trying to publish a workbook through rest api to the tableau server.
This is the below curl request which I am importing in the postman:

```
curl "https://MY_SERVER/api/3.4/sites/site-id/workbooks" -X POST -H "X-Tableau-Auth:credentials token" -H "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;" -F "request_payload=@publish-workbook.xml" -F "tableau_workbook=@MY_WORKBOOK.twbx"
```

But it is throwing this below error:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<tsResponse xmlns="http://tableau.com/api" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://tableau.com/api https://help.tableau.com/samples/en-us/rest_api/ts-api_3_18.xsd">
    <error code="406000">
        <summary>Bad Request</summary>
        <detail>Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------313748027746018569295475' not supported</detail>
    </error>
</tsResponse>
```

Also we are trying to publish datasource using postman. But same type of error is coming. Kindly help regarding this issue.

I am trying to hit this below curl from postman:

```
curl "https://MY_SERVER/api/3.4/sites/site-id/workbooks" -X POST -H "X-Tableau-Auth:credentials token" -H "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;" -F "request_payload=@publish-workbook.xml" -F "tableau_workbook=@MY_WORKBOOK.twbx"
```

I am expecting to publish the workbook in tableau server.

References:
https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref_data_sources.htm#publish_data_source

https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_concepts_publish.htm

Comment: Why are you setting `Content-Type` header as `multipart/mixed`?

Comment: @gre_gor As per documentation and cURL I am using Content - Type as multipart/mixed. If I am removing Content-Type from the header the response body is showing like below:

<error code="406000">
        <summary>Bad Request</summary>
        <detail>Content type '' not supported</detail>
</error>

Comment: @gre_gor You can refer this below document:
https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref_data_sources.htm#publish_data_source

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/11471) what you looking for?